# fieldDescription is not working for second fileUpload widget used in a single tab in aem

Tags: aem

fieldDescription property is not working on the second fileUpload widget added under the same tab in a dialog in aem. However, it is coming in the first widget added in the tab in dialog.

Comment: was your dialog is Touch UI/Classic and also Multifield ? any code snippet that causes failure can help you to suggest.

Comment: Please add some details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In aem 6.2, file Upload is creating an extra div which was overlapping field Description.
Changes made in coralui2 clientlib regarding this extra div solved the issue..
Aem 6.3 (beta version) does not have this problem.